# Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse for square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, pseudoinverse

Help me please to define Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse for square matrix.

Also, how can I use  it in order to solve linear equations?

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Penrose_pseudoinverse and if the information provided there should happen to be insufficient, please elaborate on what's missing or what you want to have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Moore-Penrose inverse of $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, denoted
by $A^{+}$, is the unique matrix $X$ satisfying the following four
Penrose equations.
\begin{eqnarray}
 (i)~  AXA = A,~   (ii)~ XAX = X, ~ (iii)~ (AX)^* = AX,~ (iv)~  (XA)^* =
 XA
 \end{eqnarray}

There are various methods to find out Moore-Penrose inverse of a matrix. For example Rank factorization method, singular value decomposition method, QR decomposition etc.
If $Ax = b$ is inconsistent then $x = A^{+}b$  represents the least square solution of minimum 2 norm.

In general $x = A^{+}b$  represents the least square solution to system $Ax = b$.
 For more detailed information refers to generalized inverse by Ben-Israel
[http://www.amazon.com/Generalized-inverses-applications-Adi-Ben-Israel/dp/0882759914](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0882759914)